# docker maven plugin error

Tags: docker, spring-boot

i am following the tutorial [Spring boot with docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

when i run

> mvn clean package docker:build

i get an error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.3.7:build (default-cli) on project
>   Project_Name: Exception caught:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: Cannot retry request
>   with a non-repeatable request entity: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]

am i missing any docker configurations here?

Answer (score 0):

docker build/pull cannot be executed concurrently.In that case, docker client needs to wait till it completes. Check once is there any

```
docker build (or) 
mvn docker:build
```

running in the same host.